# Where are the SuiteBar Delegate Controls for SharePoint 2016?

Tags: branding, suitebar

I created a "Feature" using the SuiteBarBranding, PromotedActions and SuiteLinks Delegate Controls in SharePoint 2013 however, it appears they are gone in SharePoint2016.  Is this correct? is there another option?

Bismarck

Comment: Please check here as this works in SP 2016 ...http://ericoverfield.com/move-the-sharepoint-2013-notification-and-status-bar-in-html-master-pages/

Comment: Do you get the idea?

Comment: Did you get the information whatever you want?

Comment: Kindly mark the answers so others can get benefit from it by identifying it as trusted answer.

Comment: As you already said that it helps you, That's why i am asking for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below mentioned link to understand the concept of Branding in SharePoint 2016.

[SharePoint 2016 Branding Revisit](http://blog.blumshapiro.com/blog/2016/03/11/sharepoint-2016-branding-revisit/)

[SharePoint 2016 Preview and Version 16 Branding Elements](http://ericoverfield.com/sharepoint-2016-preview-and-version-16-branding-elements/)

[SharePoint 2016 Preview Released – A First Look at Branding](http://ericoverfield.com/sharepoint-2016-preview-released-a-first-look-at-branding/)

You can get the starter master page for SharePoint 2016 from below locaion & understand the concept from it.

[Starter Master Pages – SharePoint 2016](http://blog.drisgill.com/2016/04/starter-master-pages-sharepoint-2016.html)